# Microsoft Graph - What Scope for 'List People' API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When using the Graph Explorer, I could use the 'List People' API like so:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<user id>/people
```

Where `<user id>` can be any user in the organization.

However, when I build my own app, I could only call the List People API on the logged in user. Calling it on another user gets me a permission denied response.

What Scope should I use so I can use List People on any users?

According to the documentation for the List People API

```
"The following scopes are required to execute this API: People.Read; People.ReadWrite"
```

But People.Read only `"Allows the app to read a ranked list of relevant people of the signed-in user."` and `People.ReadWrite` doesn't exist on the list of Permission scopes.

Comment: Although not an answer, can you file a doc issue on GitHub (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues) for the incorrect permission (People.ReadWrite) please?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the scope **User.ReadBasic.All** which allows you to get all users in the organization - but not all properties however.

Some resources:

- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/users
- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes

Comment: Looks like the documentation reference in the question came from a version of the page with an error. The correct scope for the API referenced is People.Read.All

Answer (score 0):

This call type needs People.Read.All which must be Admin consented for your app in order to call it.

Docs are here: [MS Graph : List People](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_people)